# Does Environment.TickCount always start at zero after cold boot?

Tags: c#, .net, time, clock

I've long been under the impression that the value of `Environment.TickCount` **starts at zero** for a system that has just been booted. The current [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.7#System_Environment_TickCount) say:

> TickCount will increment from zero to Int32.MaxValue for approximately 24.9 days, then jump to Int32.MinValue, which is a negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9 days.

The way this is worded doesn't necessarily imply that the value starts at zero, just that it will, at some point, hit zero and increment towards `Int32.MaxValue`.

I can't find any reference that explicitly states that the tick count value starts at zero after a cold boot. Is my long-held assumption incorrect?

The kind of value I am seeing is -1967939609. This is for a Windows 10 laptop that was cold booted this morning, around an hour-and-a-half ago. The laptop was shut down normally (not put to sleep, nor hibernated) yesterday afternoon around 5pm, and the power switched off at the wall socket.

If it makes any difference, I'm running the code from within VS2015 and I've tried a couple of different .Net Framework versions with the same results. The code happens to be C# but I'm guessing the results would be the same regardless of language.

Comment: You sure that laptop was not woken up from sleep or hibernation?

Comment: It says *TickCount will increment from zero*, seems clear to me.

Comment: @Evk Yes, it is shut down the same way every day. I never put it into sleep or hibernation.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3qi2yz/windows_10_shut_down_is_actually_hybernate/

Comment: Well you might not even know it's hibernated because it might be default option instead of power off.

Comment: did you take the battery out? :)

Comment: @RufusL No I did not take out the battery.

Comment: @SirRufo Looks like this might be a result of hybrid shutdown. I'm going to force a full shutdown from the command line, then report back.

Comment: A normal restart will do the same :o)

Comment: @SirRufo I just ran `shutdown /r /t 0` from the command line, then ran the code again after reboot. This seems to have reset the tick count so I am no longer getting large negative values. Thanks! If you write your comment up as a short answer I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2):

What I read in your quote is:

Startup: TickCount is at 0

24.9 days later: hits Int.MaxValue and jumps to Int.MinValue

From there your quote says "then increment **back to zero** during the next 24.9 days", after it hits 0, this cycle is repeated.

The explanation of the negative value you're seeing is simply "Windows 10" (Windows 8 has the same behavior). When you click shutdown, Windows 8/10 might not actually shut down completely (based on power settings). It might actually go into some sleep/hibernation mode and it's even possible Windows 10 wakes itself up (PC turns on without you doing anything) to install updates. This means the TickCount does not go back to 0. Fully rebooting the PC will reset the TickCount to 0.

On my Windows 7 PCs I've never seen a negative TickCount, because shutdown, means shut down completely in Windows 7.